# Limit of $\frac{x^2+2\sqrt{x^2}}{ x}$ for $x\to 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I am unable to figure out an algebraic proof to this limit problem:

$$ \lim_{ x \to 0} \frac{x^2 + 2\sqrt{x^2}}{x}. $$

Graphically, there should be no limit for it but I am unable to completely prove it algebraically.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, at least your thoughts, so other people could help you better. Good luck! Here is a guide to write Mathjax expressions:
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Marlene You are right. The typesetting confused me.

Comment: Use $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{x^2+2\sqrt{x^2}}{x}=x+\frac{2|x|}{x}$$
Now as $x\to 0$. The first term goes to $0$ but the second term goes to $\pm 2$, depending on which side you approach $0$.

Comment: Appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { { x }^{ 2 }+2\sqrt { { x }^{ 2 } }  }{ x }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { { x }^{ 2 }+2\left| x \right|  }{ x }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \left( x+2\frac { \left| x \right|  }{ x }  \right)  } \\ \lim _{ x\rightarrow 0- }{ \left( x+2\frac { \left| x \right|  }{ x }  \right) =-2 } \\ \\ \lim _{ x\rightarrow 0+ }{ \left( x+2\frac { \left| x \right|  }{ x }  \right) =2 } $$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \lim_{ x \to 0} \frac{x^2 + 2\sqrt{x^2}}{x}. $$

$$ \lim_{ x \to 0} \frac{x^2 + 2|x|}{x}. $$

We will look at the limits aproaching 0 from both sides

from the left -> 0^-
 $$ \lim_{ x \to 0} \frac{x^2 + 2x}{-x}. $$

$$ \lim_{ x \to 0} -(x + 2) = -2 $$

from the right -> 0^2
$$ \lim_{ x \to 0} \frac{x^2 + 2x}{x}. $$

$$ \lim_{ x \to 0} (x + 2) = 2 $$

-2!=2 => the limit does not exist